# How to loop through arrays inside a object in vue.js using v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**how I can loop through output object using v-for template**

```js
new Vue({
  el: app,
  data: {
    output: {
      player: [1, 5, 61, 98, 15, 315, 154, 65],
      monster: [14, 165, 113, 19, 22],
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span v-for="value in output">
    <h6>{{value.player}}</h6>
    <h6>{{value.monster}}</h6>
  </span>
</div>
```

### Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it a couple of ways,

Either loop through `output.player` and `output.monster` individually as in my snippet.

Or just nest as @LLai pointed out which helps in case there are unknown number of properties in the `output` object.

```js
new Vue({
  el: app,
  data: {
    output: {
      player: [1, 5, 61, 98, 15, 315, 154, 65],
      monster: [14, 165, 113, 19, 22],
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>
    <h6 v-for="pla in output.player">{{pla}}</h6>
    <h6 v-for="mon in output.monster">{{mon}}</h6>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes sir This is what I want , but I want this with a little tweak , I want the output will be like : one player then one monster , one player then one monster , how to do that?

Comment: @sumanbiswas is the data supposed to be in that form? or can it change? The desired functionality you need may not be possible without having to alter the `output` object. This can either be done in a `method` or you can change the source data itself.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a nested v-for. The first v-for loops through the object where `value` is the object values (in your case the array of numbers). The second v-for loops through that array

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="value in output">
      <span v-for="num in value">
          {{ num }}
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but sir i want both the array value separately, not everything at once